# interval vs flush_interval in telegraf

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have a following `telegraf` configuration

```
[agent]
  interval = "5s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "5s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = false
  quiet = false
  logfile = ""
  hostname = "$HOSTNAME"
  omit_hostname = false

[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://influxdb:8086"]
  database = "telegraf"
  username = ""
  password = ""
  retention_policy = ""
  write_consistency = "any"
  timeout = "5s"

[[inputs.docker]]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  container_names = []
  timeout = "5s"
  perdevice = true
  total = false

[[inputs.cpu]]
[[inputs.system]]
[[inputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://influxdb:8086/debug/vars"]
[[inputs.syslog]]
#   ## Specify an ip or hostname with port - eg., tcp://localhost:6514, tcp://10.0.0.1:6514
#   ## Protocol, address and port to host the syslog receiver.
#   ## If no host is specified, then localhost is used.
#   ## If no port is specified, 6514 is used (RFC5425#section-4.1).
  server = "tcp://localhost:6514"

[[inputs.socket_listener]]
# ## URL to listen on
service_address = "udp4://:8094"
data_format = "influx"
```

I need to dump data as fast as possible to my `influx DB`. I understand that it has something to do with `interval` and `flush_interval` settings ([here is what I've been reading](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.2/administration/configuration/#agent_config)), but I can't figure out what is the difference between `interval` and `flush_interval`. Would someone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 11):

I've asked the maintainer of Telegraf to provide an answer to this question. [Here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4694#issuecomment-491972462) it is:

> You can think of inputs as falling into 2 categories: polling
>   (regular) and event driven (service inputs). The interval is the
>   frequency that polling inputs plugins look for data. Most of the event
>   driven plugins do not use the interval, although the statsd plugin is
>   a notable exception.
>
> All collected data has a timestamp, this means that regardless of how
>   long it takes to send the data, it will have the timestamp of when it
>   was sampled.
>
> The flush_interval is how frequently the outputs write data. This is
>   the longest you will have to wait under normal circumstances for the
>   data to be written. The metric_batch_size setting also comes into play
>   here, if this number of new metrics are collected then the output will
>   immediately flush. In other words, Telegraf will trigger a write when
>   either metric_batch_size new metrics are collected or after
>   flush_interval, whichever comes first.